# scalaz lens from example does not work

Tags: scalaz

When i try to use `Lens.lensu` from `scalaz.7.2.15`, (i check http://eed3si9n.com/learning-scalaz/Lens.html)

```
case class Person(id: Int, name: String)

val idLens: Person @> Int = Lens.lensu(
  (p, id) => p.copy(id = id),
  _.id
)
val nameLens: Person @> String = Lens.lensu(
  (p, name) => p.copy(name = name),
  _.name
)

val c = idLens <=< nameLens
```

But i get error:

```
found   : Person @> String
[error]     (which expands to)   scalaz.LensFamily[Person,Person,String,String]
[error]  required: scalaz.LensFamily[?,?,Person,Person]
[error]     val c = idLens <=< nameLens
```

But it's the same as in example, what is bad with this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read `<=<` as "after". Then

```
idLens <=< nameLens
```

means: Use `idLens` after `nameLens`. For this to work, the "input type" of `idLens` (which is `Person`) has to match the "output type" of `nameLens`. That's why the compiler expects `LensFamily[?,?,Person,Person]` (that is, output type `Person`). But the output type of `nameLens` is `String`, not `Person`.

What type do you expect `c` to have? If you want `Person @> (Int, String)`, then use parallel composition:

```
val c = idLens *** nameLens
```